# Converting $\ln|x| = h$ to $x = e^h$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

In Kreyszig's Advanced Engineering Mathematics, section on First-Order ODEs, it is written:

---

$ dF/F = p \, dx $

$ \ln|F| = h = \int p \, dx $

Therefore, $ F = e^h$

---

However I don't understand why the absolute value for $F$ is gone.

To my understanding, a simplified version of this could be thought of as $\ln|x| = h$. Then if I write $x = e^h = e^{\ln|x|}$ just like the reasoning of the book, when I put $x = -2$, the equation would not hold true because $e^{\ln|-2|} = e^{\ln2} = 2$, not $-2$.

Comment: You're right. Maybe there are some hypotheses on $x$ which guarantee it is non-negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CAUTION:**

Upon reading the given reference, it turns out that at this point the author is not after the full solution, but after an *integrating factor*. This is why he does not care about the integration constant nor about the sign. Thus any solution can do and $e^{h(x)}$ is good enough.

This makes my answer below somewhat useless.

---

The true story is more complicated.

From

$$\frac{dF}F=p\,dx$$

we draw the indefinite solution

$$\log|F|=h+c$$

and

$$|F|=e^{h+c},$$

$$F=\pm e^{h+c}=\pm e^ce^h=Ce^h$$ where $C$ can have any sign.

Notice that the sign of $F$ may nowhere change, because that would make the integral on $F$ undefined.

---

If you have an initial condition, say $F(0)=F_0$, you can write

$$\int_{F_0}^F\frac{df}f=\int_0^x p(t)\,dt=h(x)-h(0),$$

giving

$$F=F_0e^{h(x)-h(0)}$$ and the sign of $F$ is determined by that of $F_0$.

Comment: Yes the author was talking about integrating factors in that part of the book. I wrongly thought that info would be unimportant and omitted it from my question. Thanks for taking the time to check the reference! So to recheck my understanding of your answer, There are two possible integrating factors(positive and negative) so the author just chose the positive one, right?

Comment: @linearAlg: read my answer. There is an infinity of integrating factors.

Comment: oh ok there are infinite amount of integrating factors because $C=\pm e^c$ can be any real number except zero. The author chose the simplest one where $C=1$

Answer (score 1):

You're right. You can see also it as follows :

As $|x|  = \sqrt x^2$, $\ln |x| = \frac{\ln(x^2)}{2}$ and then
$$x^2 = e^{2h}$$

Therefore, choosing between $x = e^h$ or $x = -e^h$ only depends on some other conditions you might know about $x$, that may be omitted in the book you are looking at.